# Change the user name debian-sys-maint in Debian mariadb

Tags: linux, debian, mariadb

The account "debian-sys-maint" in Debian mysql/mariadb is important to maintain the DB system function normally. It needs full administrative privileges, as some people has discussed in [What is the debian-sys-maint MySQL user (and more)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9948/what-is-the-debian-sys-maint-mysql-user-and-more).

But recently we were audited by our officers. One of the security issue the auditors pointed out is that, in a database, there should be only one account with the full administrative privileges to access the whole database. Further, this account should not be a special name that everybody can guess. Thus, the auditors seriously questioned about the "debian-sys-maint" account in our mariadb. They suggested us to remove it, or rename it, provided that there is no other accounts with administrative privileges.

My question is, is it possible to have another account to replace "debian-sys-maint" ? I saw that in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf:

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = ****************
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = ****************
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

It looks like that this special account can be changed to the other name, as long as if we set the account name and password correctly in the "user" and "password" parameters in debian.cnf, and create that account in mariadb with the command:

```
CREATE USER '<username>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<username>'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And finally remove all the other administrative accounts. Then everything will work just fine, including start/stop mariadb, upgrade mariadb by dpkg system, .... etc. There is no risk of database damage in future upgrade. Am I right ?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

T.H.Hsieh

[Update]

Thank you very much for your responses. Unfortunately changing our auditors is not possible, because they were assigned directly by our government. I guess that they know some basics of general databases, but not the details. And also possible that this is the
first time we were audited. We might revealed too many unnecessary aspects and leaded them to more questions.

In any case, for an experiment, we got a "white-mouse" system, Debian-11.8, with the system "debian-sys-maint" account replaced by the other one, following the procedures I have posted. We will test whether the system could run well or not, for at least more than half or one years. During this period we expect that we will have several chances of reboot, recover from losing of power, and upgrade.

In the meanwhile, we will respond the auditor the necessity of the "debian-sys-maint" in the system. We probably need the "official" document of explanation of that account, either from Debian or from Mariadb. Could you please point out where could I found this official document?

Thank you.

T.H.Hsieh

[Update]

I tested creating an account in mariadb, with the full administrative privileges, and identified via unix_socket, to replace the "root" or "debian-sys-maint" accounts. This account should also exists in Linux account as a normal user. But this way it cannot work in Debian maintenance system.

For example, when doing

```
/etc/init.d/mariadb reload
```

the script will read /etc/mysql/debian.cnf to get the credential for the administrative account. It needs "root" privilege. But if I run this command with "root" account, I cannot login into mariadb as the administrative account, because it is identified via unix_socket.

Therefore, if we want to play this trick, this administrative account should be created with password identification, and put the account name and password into /etc/mysql/debian.cnf.

We will continue this test to see whether there are other side effects.

T.H.Hsieh

Comment: yes it is possible, but to gain the credentials for this user, the emeny has  already got access to the system. do they also claim, that root is on every f... single unix/Linux machine on earth? if yes I would think about these kind of authors. I mean there are a lot of groups and default users, do they also claim that for a risk?

Comment: Possibly related: https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants

Comment: Sounds like changing your auditor might be a more sensible approach

Comment: Debian doesn't use the debian-sys-maint user anymore (it just uses plain system root without password but authenticated through unix socket authentication). AFAIK since at least Debian 10. But it might be keeping it if that's upgraded from a former installation where it was present.

Comment: I see. Interesting. So we could try to create an account identified via unix_socket with administrative privileges to replace the root account.

Comment: I'm not sure of the (EOL) Debian 10 status. But for Debian 11 and 12: https://salsa.debian.org/mariadb-team/mariadb-server/-/blob/mariadb-10.5.21/debian/mariadb-server-10.5.postinst#L178 , https://salsa.debian.org/mariadb-team/mariadb-server/-/blob/debian/1%2510.11.4-1_deb12u1/debian/mariadb-server.postinst#L176

Comment: I checked my local installation of Debian 10.13. It also has the same comment in mariadb-server-10.3.postinst, except the last "In the long run the goal is to obsolete this file." sentence. Thank you very much for your information.